# Ошибка Illegal character range near index 12

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, qregularexpression

Использую данное регулярное выражение для отсеивания значений:

```
public static String reg(String input) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b[a-zа-я-@.]{4,17}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
```

получаю

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 13
```

Что не так? Пробовал как UTF-8, так и cp1251 кодировки. Причем в онлайне все работает отлично(regex101)

Comment: причем при использовании регулярного выражения типа \b\p{Ll}+ IDEA не видит русских символов(опять таки в онлайн сервисах все исправно срабатывает)

Comment: В описании паттернов сказано, если хотите использовать служебные символы, например -, то их нужно ставить в определенное место. Для дефиса это начало или конец строки. Так же для того чтобы выбирать, например, любые буквенные символы можно использовать \p{L}

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в дефисе после символа "я". Однако до сих по не понял, почему при \b\p{Ll}+ IDEA отказывается замечать русские символы.